# Trying to Make osclass work

Tags: mysql, localhost, osclass, mysql-error-1067

I am trying to install osclass on my wampserver and am getting the whenever I click next

Can't create the database structure. Error number: 1067

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the installer SQL files. Prepend this:

```
SET sql_mode = "";
```

In the following files:

```
oc-includes/osclass/installer/struct.sql
oc-includes/osclass/installer/basic_data.sql
oc-includes/osclass/installer/pages.sql
```